# How can I get the real length of char*? Different between strlen and sizeof(target)/sizeof(target*)?

Tags: c++, arrays

This is my test code.

```
string str=string("def");
const char* c_str=str.c_str();
char* charString=(char*)"abc";
char* target;

cout << "str : "<< str<< endl;
cout << "c_str : "<< c_str << endl;
cout << "charString : " << charString << endl << endl;


cout << "string length : " << str.length() << endl;
cout << "c_str length : " << strlen(c_str) << endl;
cout << "c_str array length : " << (sizeof(c_str)/sizeof(*c_str)) << endl;
cout << "charString length : " << strlen(charString) << endl;
cout << "charString array length " << (sizeof(charString)/sizeof(*charString)) << endl<< endl;

target = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*2);
target = (char*)"ab";
cout << "target : " << target << endl;
cout << "target strlen : " << strlen(target) << endl;
cout << "target arr length : " << (sizeof(target)/sizeof(char)) << endl;
```

This is result of above code.

```
str : def
c_str : def
charString : abc

string length : 3
c_str length : 3
c_str array length : 8
charString length : 3
charString array length 8

target : ab
target strlen : 2
target arr length : 8
```

In str, c_str, charString case, strlen is 3 and array length is 8.
8 includes encoding and '\0' character at last. Right?

So, I really don't understand target case.

I allocate memory 2 byte.
And allocate 2 characters.
strlen is right.

- But why target array length is 8 like array length of c_str and charString? Why target's array length isn't less than c_str and charString ?
- Last question, I send message char* including message length in message header. If I want to calculate the message length from string.c_str(), do I have to calculate like (sizeof(target)/sizeof(*target)) ?

Comment: Arrays and pointers aren't the same thing. http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html

Comment: `sizeof(c_str)` is the size in bytes of the pointer (4 on 32-bit systems, 8 on 64-bit ones). It's unrelated to the size of the data the pointer points to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sizeof(x)/(sizeof(*x)` is *basically* a mistake. The only way this basic construct makes sense is if `x` is an array--but in this case, `*x` only makes sense by converting the name of the array to a pointer to its first element (which, yes, does happen implicitly), then dividing by the size of that item.

At least theoretically, `sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0])` is a little better. There's no observable difference in actual use, but at least to somebody looking at it, the use of `[0]` might provide some indication that this is really intended to be applied (only) to an array, not a pointer.

Assuming they are applied to arrays, they still have an effect that's fundamentally different from `strlen`. `strlen` assumes its argument is a NUL-terminated byte sequence. That means it counts bytes starting from the address you pass, until it encounters a byte containing the value `'\0'`. That might be shorter than the array, or (if the array doesn't contain an NTBS) potentially much longer. In short, `strlen` tries to tell you the current length of a string, whereas the `sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0])` attempts to tell you the maximum string size a particular array *could* potentially hold. These will coincide *primarily* when applied to an initialized array, like: `char foo[] = "Something";`.

One other minor difference as well: `strlen` only includes the number of characters *before* the terminating NUL, where `sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0])` includes all the storage of the array, one larger than the maximum length of NUL-terminated string you can store there.

If you apply either of these to a pointer instead of an array, you can plan on normally getting bad results (the "normally" weasel wording being to cover the corner case: if you happen to have an array exactly the same size as a pointer, it'll work, much like a broken clock giving the right time twice a day).

In C++, you're usually better off with something like this:

```
template <class T, size_t N>
constexpr size_t elements(T (&array)[N]) {
    return N;
}
```

This requires that you pass it an array by reference. If you attempt to pass a pointer instead of an array, you'll get a compiler error instead of an incorrect answer.

Of course, in C++ you generally want to avoid using `strlen` as well--you can normally use `std::string` (or `std::string_view`) and use its `length()` or `size()` member.

Comment: Might want to declare `elements` constexpr to replicate the compile time evaluation that sizeof offers

Answer (score 1):

The line `const char* c_str=str.c_str()` means:

1. Get the **pointer/address (a 32 or 64 bits integer)** of the memory used for storing the sring "def" (inside the str object).
2. Store this **pointer/address (a 32 or 64 bits integer)** inside `c_str`.

`c_str` never contains the string but it contains a `pointer/address (a 32 or 64 bit integer)`

The `sizeof(c_str)` returns the size used in memory by `c_str`. In your case, you use a 64 bits compiler (so address are 64 bits). So `c_str` returns `8` (we need 8 bytes of memory for storing 64 bits number).

Then `*c_str` will give you the first character (ascii value) stored in the string. An ascii value is stored in a char and the memory needed for storing a char is `1`.

So `sizeof(*c_str)` will always returns `1`.
It's why it's make no sense to write `sizeof(c_str)/sizeof(*c_str)`. This expression is constant and will always returns 8/1 => 8 (nothing to do with the size of the string).

When you work with C string, it's better to use (`strlen`, `strcopy`, etc). Those functions will return you the excepted result.

Comment: Thanks for your help.