# C++, reason why casting (from string to const unsigned char* array) is resizing this string from 20 byte to 16 byte-equivalent?

Tags: c++, crypto++, reinterpret-cast

I'm making some experiments with Crypto++ library, I don't understand why before that `reinterpret_cast` the length is 20 byte and after is only 8 chars instead of 10. Thank you very much for your attention.

P.S. I'm sorry if the question isn't well posed according to the guidelines, I'm new here. Maybe it's not very general but I hope it can be useful to others nonetheless.

```cpp
#include "cryptopp/cryptlib.h"
#include "cryptopp/sha.h"
#include "cryptopp/filters.h"
#include "cryptopp/hex.h"
#include "cryptopp/files.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace CryptoPP;
    
int main (){
    std::string msg = "Yoda said, Do or do not. There is no try.";
    std::string digest;
        
    SHA1 hash;
    hash.Update((const byte*)msg.data(), msg.size());
    digest.resize(hash.DigestSize());
    hash.Final((byte*)&digest[0]);
    
    std::cout << "Message: " << msg << std::endl;
    
    std::cout << "Digest: "<<digest<<std::endl;
    //StringSource(digest, true, new Redirector(encoder));
    //std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(digest).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout<<digest.size()<<std::endl;


    //this is the line......
    const unsigned char* decoded = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>( digest.c_str() );   


    std::cout << "Length of array = " << (sizeof(decoded)/sizeof(*decoded)) << std::endl;
    //byte decoded[] = digest;
    std::string encoded;
    
    HexEncoder encoder;
    encoder.Put(decoded, sizeof(decoded));
    encoder.MessageEnd();
    
    //word64 size = encoder.MaxRetrievable(); 
    int size=encoder.MaxRetrievable(); std::cout<<size<<std::endl;
    if(size)
    {
        encoded.resize(size);       
        encoder.Get((byte*)&encoded[0], encoded.size());
    }
    
    std::cout << encoded << std::endl;
}
```

This is the output:

```
Message: Yoda said, Do or do not. There is no try.
Digest: -y;{:r79R
NSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE
20
Length of array = 8
16
05C0042DF9A7793B
```

What I was really trying to do was just to convert the result of the hash into an hexadecimal string that I could manipulate. The example on https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/SHA only redirects the result through a pipeline to the terminal, but I wanted to have access to the encoded string. But after making that modification, I found out the digest is many digits shorter than the original, thus my attempt to find out why.

This was the original code basically from Crypto++ Wiki:

```cpp
#include "cryptopp/cryptlib.h"
#include "cryptopp/sha.h"
#include "cryptopp/filters.h"
#include "cryptopp/hex.h"
#include "cryptopp/files.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace CryptoPP;
    
int main(){ 
    HexEncoder encoder(new FileSink(std::cout));
        
    std::string msg = "Yoda said, Do or do not. There is no try.";
    std::string digest;
        
    SHA1 hash;
    hash.Update((const byte*)msg.data(), msg.size());
    digest.resize(hash.DigestSize());
    hash.Final((byte*)&digest[0]);
        
    std::cout << "Message: " << msg << std::endl;
        
    std::cout << "Digest: ";
    StringSource(digest, true, new Redirector(encoder));
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and this was the output with the right length (160 bits):

```
05C0042DF9A7793B7BDE3AB9724C08CF37398652
```

Comment: I don't think `sizeof` does what you think it does.

Comment: Maybe I should just split the question in two being it now about 2 quite different problems?

Comment: That's a lot of code to demonstrate *"before that `reinterpret_cast` the length is 20 byte and after is only 8 chars instead of 10."* Why do you need more than about four lines (initialize a variable, show length 20, cast, and show length 8) to demonstrate this issue? Throwing in stuff about encoding obfuscates the question, making it less useful to future readers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get the real length of char\*? Different between strlen and sizeof(target)/sizeof(target\*)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44579547/how-can-i-get-the-real-length-of-char-different-between-strlen-and-sizeoftarg)

Answer (score 1):

Your use of `sizeof()` is wrong.  You are taking the size of a pointer, not the size of the data being pointed at.  You can't use `sizeof()` to calculate the size of an array from just a pointer to the array.

Since your `decoded` data is stored in a `std::string`, you need to use `std::string::size()` to get its size, just like you are doing everywhere else in your code, eg:

```cpp
const unsigned char* decoded = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>( digest.c_str() );   

std::cout << "Length of array = " << digest.size() << std::endl;
...
encoder.Put(decoded, digest.size());
...
```

Comment: Thank you, so what You are saying is that the casting is right, the resizing doesn't happen there and there's no reason I should check the lenght of "decoded"? Because "decoded" doesn't support the size() method as far as I've now seen being a pointer

Comment: @encelado The cast is fine. The resize happens when you call `digest.resize()`. `decoded` is just a pointer to binary data in memory, it has no methods of its own.

Comment: actually if I increase the size in the resize() argument the lenght of the output stays the same, and can't really figure out what that means. But putting a smaller number decreses the output. That made me think that the size had already shrinked for some previous reason. Oh, I'm sorry, only now I realized it was the sizeof(decoded) in encoder.Put() that had to be changed... Thank you very much! Now it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

That's because `sizeof` returns the size of the type of the operand.
`unsigned char const*` is a pointer to an `unsigned char` (ignoring cv-qualifiers), on a 64 bit machine, that's a 64 bit pointer, 8 bytes…
[Live example on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/jsff11Pso)

If you know the data is a NUL terminated byte string, then
you could use `std::strlen()`, to check the size.
In any case, you can (and probably should) use the member function `std::string::size()`, which will return the size of the container. eg:

```cpp
std::string x;
// some API populates x.data()
const auto x_size = x.size();
```

Comment: Ok thank you very much, so that isn't the right way to measure the size of the array... I admit I just copied it from an other answer having forgotten pretty much all (the very little I knew)about arrays since I've been using vectors

Comment: You can't use `strlen()` on a pointer to **binary** data (such as an unencoded hash).  The data may have embedded `0x00` bytes in it, or may not have any `0x00` bytes at all.  The correct solution is to use the `size()` of the container that is holding the bytes, or the size reported by the original hasher.

Comment: "You can't use strlen() on a pointer to binary data (such as an unencoded hash). " I agree, in this case using std::string::length() or std::string::size() is a solution. Another would be to use the cursor of the file buffer (end - beg == byte size). I'll correct that right away, thank you.